# How to place dots into the number with Python?

Tags: python, string-formatting

How can I automatically place dots by separating it with 3 digits in a group beginning from the right?

Example:

```
in: 1234; out 1.234
in: 12345678; out 12.345.678
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for a thousands-separator. Format your number with the [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) to using *commas* as the thousands separator, then replace the commas with dots:

```
>>> format(1234, ',').replace(',', '.') 
'1.234'
>>> format(12345678, ',').replace(',', '.') 
'12.345.678'
```

Here the `','` format signals that the decimal number should be formatted with a thousands-separator (see the [Format Specification Mini-language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)).

The same can be achieved in a wider string format with the `str.format()` method, where placeholders in the template are replaced with values:

```
>>> 'Some label for the value: {:,}'.format(1234).replace(',', '.')
'Some label for the value: 1,234'
```

but then you run the risk of accidentally replacing other full stops in the output string too!

Your other option would be to use the locale-dependent `'n'` format, but that requires your machine to be configured for a locale that sets the right [`LC_NUMERIC`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.localeconv) options.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple solution:

```
>>> a = 12345678
>>> "{:,}".format(a)
'12,345,678'
>>> "{:,}".format(a).replace(",", ".")
'12.345.678'
>>>
```

This uses the [`.format`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method of a string to add the comma separators and then the [`.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method to change those commas to periods.

Comment: Rule of thumb: when your `str.format()` template has **just** the placeholder (so `str[0] == '{' and str[-1] == '}' and str.count('{') == 1`), just use the `format()` function and don't bother with a placeholder. The `format()` function takes a value and the formatter (everything after the `:` in the format spec for a given placeholder).

Comment: Good idea.  I'll remember it for future.